# pyparsing scanning files with scanString

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to scan a file with pyparsing. There is a method as named scanString in pyparsing and it does;

```
   >>> name = pp.Word(pp.alphas)
   >>> text = "**** Farcical aquatic  ceremony"
   >>> for result, start, end in name.scanString(text):
   ...     print "Found {0} at [{1}:{2}]".format(result, start, end)
   ... 
   Found ['Farcical'] at [5:13]
   Found ['aquatic'] at [14:21]
   Found ['ceremony'] at [23:31]
```

But I want to scan a txt file with words in a sentence. Above scanString scans words in the sentence where the words are. Is there a way to scan a file? Or else, does scanString work only like above?

Comment: Can you elaborate a lil bit more, its not clear what your are trying to ask.

Comment: For example; i have a example.txt file and I have some sentences like "I like Tokyo." and I want to search for these words ("I", "like", "Tokyo") in the example.txt file. Can i do this with scanString method? @hashcode55

Comment: `scanString` only works on strings, but it is not difficult to read the contents of a text file into a string, and then take it from there (assuming the file is not gigabytes in size).

Comment: There are other methods besides `scanString` that you can use as well, such as `searchString`, `parseString`, and `parseFile`.  See the online docs at https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/